# jlink executable :- /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jlink does not exist. Error is coming while running npx react-native run-android command?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

jlink executable :- /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jlink does not exist. Error is coming while running npx react-native run-android command ?

Note :- jdk installed and environment path is already set.

need the solution for this error